# How to pass parameters programmatically in testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a framework, where in one method it returns two Excel sheet rows say:

```
Row[0]="Name","Age","Location"
Row[1]="Uday","34","India"
```

Here I call my TestNG testcase as below.

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { myCls.Class });
testng.run()
```

**But how I can pass above two rows of data to my class(myCls)?**

I need to pass these values to my testcase(say: class myCls) which have a @Test method.

I heard about **@DataProvider** in TestNG, but I don't know how to use in the above code.

Comment: Either use @DataProvider or use Apache POI to read the values and use it in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand from below example

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ExampleTest2 {

@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36),"mytest1"},
   { "Anne", new Integer(37),"mytest2"},
 };
}

@BeforeClass
public void before() {
    System.out.println("before");
}

@Test (dataProvider = "test1")
public void testExample2(String s,Integer i,String t) {
    System.out.println("test2:: "+s+" Integer : "+i+" Hello "+t);
}

@AfterClass
public void after(){
    System.out.println("After");
    }
}
```

Refer below link for further details.
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

Comment: I have already gone through the TestNG documentation, in the above ex. u have kept the createData in the same class and you are calling that provider as described in the TestNG documentation, but i am looking something in Java class it has two rows(Row) of Excel data, that i need to pass to my TestNG Testcase. How can i call or pass this data to testcase.

Answer (score 0):

Other than `@DataProvider`, you can also use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to read the values from the excel file and use it in your tests. See this sample code below for reading the values from your excel file.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
//..
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xlsx"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//get row 0
Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
//get cell 0
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
//print value of cell
System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
```

Simply use the cells value in your tests. Once you have read the data, you can store it in an ArrayList and pass it (what Im saying is create a separate method to read this data that returns an ArrayList or whichever data structure you like).

Comment: My question is not related to how to read data from Excel, rather it is how to pass parameters(in my case two rows of excel data) to a testng class(text case with @Test method)

Comment: Once you have read the data, you can store it in an ArrayList and pass it (what Im saying is create a separate method to read this data that return an ArrayList or whichever data structure you like).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **@DataProvider** , then it returns a 2D object array, i.e it returns 1 row at a time, if you have 2 rows in ur excel then ur test case will execute twice, 1st time for the 1st row and 2nd time for the 2nd row. If u need a more specific code for this as in how it works, do let me know.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is you are reading data in a java class and you want to pass it to a test in testNG class? Is this correct? if yes, then there is a better way of doing this. you can create a testNG class, add your test and data provider in same class, read data from excel in data provider and pass it to the test case. whatever data you read in data provider it must return an Object array. hopw this helps

```
 public class NewTestNGClass{

   @Test(dataProvider = "login")
   public void sample(String uname, String passwd) {
       LoginActions.submit_login(uname,passwd);
   }


   @DataProvider(name = "login")
   public Object[][] loginData() {
        Object[][] arrayObject = TestBaseUtil.getExcelData("D://data_xls.xls","user");
        return arrayObject;
   }
 }
```